# Send a image to server program written in PHP via JavaFX

Tags: php, image, javafx, server

I am making an desktop `javafx`  application for school which work online server communication via json and php.  I want to send a image file taken form java application to php server

Comment: Add some code that you already tried
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a http library like [unirest](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/) to make your http request. sending images will be in the form
`Unirest.post('URL_TO_POST_TO')
     .header("accept", "application/json")
     .field("image", new File(pathToImage))
     .asJson();`